# Fargate errors when frontend service tries to communicate with backend service via Service Discovery

Tags: http, https, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a frontend app in Fargate (ECS) in a private subnet exposed to internet through an Application Load Balancer. My frontend makes API calls to my backend apps, also in Fargate, same VPC.

Users calls to my frontend are made via HTTPS, but my frontend communicates with my backend via HTTP (AWS Service Discovery - AWS Cloud Map). This way, the user browser is showing the error "blocked: mixed content" since half of the communication is made via HTTPS and the other half uses HTTP.

[infra here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij9a3.png)

As far as I know and had been searching, it is not possible to use a SSL/TLS certificate with Service Discovery.

I've made a lot of researches and couldn't find something really useful. I also tried to create an internal load balancer for each backend service but the communication is timing out, it only works when I have a VPN connected.

What am I missing here? Do I need an internal load balancer in front of each backend service to attach a certificate between frontend and backend? What is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Users calls to my frontend are made via HTTPS, but my frontend communicates with my backend via HTTP (AWS Service Discovery - AWS Cloud Map). This way, the user browser is causing the error "blocked: mixed content" since half of the communication is made via HTTPS and the other half uses HTTP.

The user's browser wouldn't know anything about this if the communication was happening between the front-end **server** and the back-end server. Apparently you have front-end **client** JavaScript code running in the user's web browser trying to access the backend server directly.

If you want to access the backend server directly from the user's web browser, then service discovery won't work, because service discovery is only for traffic that is inside the VPC. And of course by trying to use service discovery in this way you are also causing a security issue which the browser is correctly blocking you from doing. You will need to add another load balancer, or another listener on your current load balancer, that exposes the backend API to the Internet.

Alternatively you could use a reverse proxy like Nginx on your front-end server to send backend API requests to the backend service, and then have your client-side JavaScript code send all requests to the front-end server.

Comment: Hmmmm, got it. So ideally I should have a Front End server like Next.js for React.js, then I could handle all the requests on it and it would send to my backend privately, right?

Comment: I don't use Next.js so I'm not sure if/how it proxies backend requests like that, but if that's what it does then yes. I've seen so many people ask questions on here about this exact problem you are having, that said they were using Next.js and it was only handling backend requests like they wanted during the server-side rendering phase, not during client-side rendering, that I'm inclined to say that Next.js does not proxy requests like that so it would be of no added benefit here. I recommended Nginx for that in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: In that case, the Nginx would need to be exposed, right?

Comment: Yes it would be the front-end server that all requests go to. You either need to expose the backend server to the Internet, or you need to expose **something** to the Internet that will proxy those requests to the backend.